# Visual Studio Installer project detected no Dependencies

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, vtk, setup-project

I am working on a QT+VTK project with C++, finally the project completed compilation in release mode and has no errors . Then I want to create a setup project to pack my QT+VTK project in order to run on any computer. I use the [Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects).

I following the normal steps, Add a Setup project in my VTK Solution and select my main project as  'Project output' in Application Folder.

But in Setup project there is no Dependencies be Detected.Like the picture below,just a single "Main output" in Application Folder.

[image: screenshot from my project]

I used CMAKE to setup Environment of my Project,Therefore the path of dependencies is correct.

Strangely , if I reopen the project, **Sometimes** it shows the correct required dll file under the setup project. But as soon as I refresh or build setup project, it disappears! And I will get a single .exe file without any .dll.

Anyone know this weird problem? and how can I fix it? I can provide screenshots of the project environment settings if necessary.
I don't want to manually find the dependencies one by one, or maybe there is a better Installer tool to recommend?

Comment: ***maybe there is a better Installer tool to recommend?*** I do this in CMake and have it generate NSIS based installers for my Qt + VTK projects with visual studio. With that said it was a bit of work to setup (took several 8+ hour days to get working).

Comment: Could you please explain more how is your solution worked? ,I use "dumpbin" to analyse the required dependency and write a batch file to search and copy them. It works,but for this problem of visual studio I still have no idea.

Comment: With CMake I track each .dll needed. With that said CMake can determine the dependent dlls using this: [https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/BundleUtilities.html](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/BundleUtilities.html)

Comment: Here is an answer that uses this to create an installer: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52182464/add-fixup-bundle-result-to-cpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52182464/add-fixup-bundle-result-to-cpack)

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that cmake could be used for packaging, I just used it to configure the environment. So I just need to add the command about cpack to my cmakelist.txt file, right? I'm not familiar with cpack yet, do you have any complete cmakelist.txt that I can refer to?